# Joining Multiple Arrays under some Logic

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have different arrays as follows:-

```
$reservations = ['reservationid' => '1', 'reservationid' => '2', 'reservationid' => '3'] 

$reservedrooms = ['reservationid'=> '1', 'roomno' => '1', 'reservationid' => '1', 'roomid'=>'2', 'reservationid' => '2', 'roomid'=>'3']

$guestdata = ['reservationid'=> '1', 'guestname' => 'Adam', 'reservationid' => '1', 'guestname'=>'Abraham', 'reservationid' => '2', 'guestname'=>'David']
```

How to join them so that they can be used as nested array with similar reservationids in CodeIgniter? I have also sent it to client side using Json and be depicted in JQuery Datatables. How to achieve it logically?

I have following code which is running on multiple tables

```
$this->db->from('hotelbrancheshasreservations');
$this->db->join('reservation', 'reservation.reservationid = hotelbrancheshasreservations.reservations_reservationsid');
$this->db->join('reservedrooms', 'reservedrooms.reservation_reservationid = hotelbrancheshasreservations.reservations_reservationsid');
$this->db->where( array('hotelbranches_hotelbranchesid'=>$branchid, 'status'=>$status));
$reservations = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

I want result array as follows:-

```
$result = array (
"reservationid" => '1', 'rooms' => Array(
    "roomno" => '1',
    "roomno" => '2'), 'guests' => Array('guestid' => '1', 'guestname' => 'Adam', 'guestid' => '2', 'guestname' => 'David',) );
```

Comment: How do you create these 3 arrays. I am guessing 3 seperate queries on your database. Show that code as that is what needs to be amended so that you get **ONE USEFUL array** back from the database.

Comment: How can you have duplicate keys in your arrays ?

Comment: these are actually three tables which have different data items but are connected through foreign key relationship. I want to have an array which shall hold the reservation data as parent array and rooms & guest data as child arrays.

Comment: these are duplicated because these are not primary keys. table has some column which acts as primary keys. these are actually foreign keys.

Comment: @JamshaidSabir Yes, but this array `$reservations = ['reservationid' => '1', 'reservationid' => '2', 'reservationid' => '3'] ` and the two other are impossible in PHP because there are duplicate keys. If you try to create an array with this configuration, you'll end up with just `['reservationid' => '3']`. So could you show a real var_dump (or print_r) version of these arrays ?

Comment: @roberto06 the var dump of result set is given in the answer. Check it

Answer (score 0):

The following code is run in model class and then is returned back to controller. Then controller echos json object array to client side.

```
$this->$db->trans_start();


$this->$db->from('hotelbrancheshasreservations');
$this->$db->join('reservation', 'reservation.reservationid = hotelbrancheshasreservations.reservations_reservationsid');
$this->$db->join('reservedrooms', 'reservedrooms.reservation_reservationid = hotelbrancheshasreservations.reservations_reservationsid');
$this->$db->where( array('hotelbranches_hotelbranchesid'=>$branchid, 'status'=>$status));
$reservations = $this->$db->get()->result_array();
$this->$db->trans_complete();
return $reservations;
```

The above code returned following array after joining and in this solution problem is that if a reservation has more than one reserved rooms then that row is included in result set for multiple times and thats why i need to nest the reserved rooms in reservation array.

following is result set:

```
{"data":[{"hotelbrancheshasreservationsid":"18","hotelbranches_hotelbranchesid":"1","reservations_reservationsid":"KHAN2016Q221","status":"active","tblid":"19","reservationid":"KHAN2016Q221","startdate":"2016-05-16 11:59:00","enddate":"2016-05-21 11:59:00","duration":"","noofroom":"","reservationdate":"2016-05-22 01:41:32","guestarrivaldate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","gestdeparturedate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","totalreservedadults":"","totalreservedchilds":"","totalreservationcharges":"","createdby":"","createdon":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","lastmodifiedby":"","lastmodifiedon":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","reservedroomsid":"1","reservation_reservationid":"KHAN2016Q221","hotelrooms_hotelroomsid":"1"},{"hotelbrancheshasreservationsid":"145","hotelbranches_hotelbranchesid":"1","reservations_reservationsid":"KHAN2016Q3-34","status":"active","tblid":"146","reservationid":"KHAN2016Q3-34","startdate":"2016-07-24 00:22:31","enddate":"2016-07-25 00:22:37","duration":"1 days 6 seconds ","noofroom":"2","reservationdate":"2016-07-24 00:26:51","guestarrivaldate":"2016-07-24 00:26:30","gestdeparturedate":"2016-07-25 00:26:35","totalreservedadults":"2","totalreservedchilds":"2","totalreservationcharges":"1200","createdby":"1","createdon":"2016-07-24 00:23:05","lastmodifiedby":"","lastmodifiedon":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","reservedroomsid":"91","reservation_reservationid":"KHAN2016Q3-34","hotelrooms_hotelroomsid":"2"},{"hotelbrancheshasreservationsid":"145","hotelbranches_hotelbranchesid":"1","reservations_reservationsid":"KHAN2016Q3-34","status":"active","tblid":"146","reservationid":"KHAN2016Q3-34","startdate":"2016-07-24 00:22:31","enddate":"2016-07-25 00:22:37","duration":"1 days 6 seconds ","noofroom":"2","reservationdate":"2016-07-24 00:26:51","guestarrivaldate":"2016-07-24 00:26:30","gestdeparturedate":"2016-07-25 00:26:35","totalreservedadults":"2","totalreservedchilds":"2","totalreservationcharges":"1200","createdby":"1","createdon":"2016-07-24 00:23:15","lastmodifiedby":"","lastmodifiedon":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","reservedroomsid":"92","reservation_reservationid":"KHAN2016Q3-34","hotelrooms_hotelroomsid":"1"},{"hotelbrancheshasreservationsid":"146","hotelbranches_hotelbranchesid":"1","reservations_reservationsid":"KHAN2016Q3-35","status":"active","tblid":"147","reservationid":"KHAN2016Q3-35","startdate":"2016-07-25 22:05:36","enddate":"2016-07-26 22:05:41","duration":"1 days 5 seconds ","noofroom":"1","reservationdate":"2016-07-25 22:08:07","guestarrivaldate":"2016-07-25 22:07:53","gestdeparturedate":"2016-07-26 22:07:57","totalreservedadults":"1","totalreservedchilds":"","totalreservationcharges":"1500","createdby":"1","createdon":"2016-07-25 22:05:52","lastmodifiedby":"","lastmodifiedon":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","reservedroomsid":"93","reservation_reservationid":"KHAN2016Q3-35","hotelrooms_hotelroomsid":"4"},{"hotelbrancheshasreservationsid":"147","hotelbranches_hotelbranchesid":"1","reservations_reservationsid":"KHAN2016Q3-36","status":"active","tblid":"148","reservationid":"KHAN2016Q3-36","startdate":"2016-07-26 10:54:05","enddate":"2016-07-27 10:54:10","duration":"1 days 5 seconds ","noofroom":"1","reservationdate":"2016-07-26 10:56:15","guestarrivaldate":"2016-07-26 10:55:58","gestdeparturedate":"2016-07-27 10:56:03","totalreservedadults":"1","totalreservedchilds":"","totalreservationcharges":"700","createdby":"1","createdon":"2016-07-26 10:54:28","lastmodifiedby":"","lastmodifiedon":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","reservedroomsid":"94","reservation_reservationid":"KHAN2016Q3-36","hotelrooms_hotelroomsid":"3"}]}
```